# Effect of including/excluding predictors on beta estimation in linear regression

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, predictor

I'm interested in the effect on beta estimation of including/excluding independent variables in linear regression.

I've made this data below:

```
set.seed(50)
predictor1 <- rnorm(10, 3, 1)
predictor2 <- rnorm(10, 6, 1)
```

I've also simulated a model using these data, with an intercept of 2, a beta of 50 for `predictor1` and a beta
of 2 for `predictor2`:

```
response <- 2 + (50 * predictor1) + (2*predictor2)
```

A linear regression in `R` correctly calculates the intercept and both the betas:

```
summary(lm(response ~ predictor1 + predictor2))

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ predictor1 + predictor2)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-4.150e-14 -6.833e-15  1.100e-15  9.879e-15  2.757e-14 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2.000e+00  8.194e-14 2.441e+13   <2e-16 ***
predictor1  5.000e+01  7.730e-15 6.468e+15   <2e-16 ***
predictor2  2.000e+00  1.353e-14 1.479e+14   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.081e-14 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1,  Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 2.095e+31 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

However, a linear regression with only `predictor2` in the model calculates a beta of -3.467 for `predictor2`:

```
summary(lm(response ~ predictor2))

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ predictor2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-75.201 -24.049   5.193  38.423  56.074 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  171.133    177.588   0.964    0.363
predictor2    -3.467     30.872  -0.112    0.913

Residual standard error: 47.58 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.001574,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1232 
F-statistic: 0.01261 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.9134
```

Here is plot of `response` against `predictor1` and `predictor2`, with line of best fit calculated through regression:

```
 library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(predictor2 , response )) + geom_point() + 
  geom_point(aes(predictor1 , response )) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = 2) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 2, slope = 50) + 
  ylim(0, 300) + 
  xlim(0,10)
```

[image]

And here is plot of just `response` against just `predictor2`, against with line of best fit calculated through regression:

```
 ggplot(dat, aes(predictor2 , response )) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_abline(intercept = 171.133, slope = -3.467)
```

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How did the linear regression arrive at a beta of -3.467 in the second model, when the real beta is 2? Or in other words, how has excluding `predictor1` from the second model caused `predictor2`'s beta to drop by over 5?
2. Is someone able to provide a visual display of how linear regression calculates betas?

Answer (score 3):

Note, you have no noise in your data. The dependent variable is a deterministic function of all covariates - no wonder your regression gets the exact coefficients (betas) in the first regression. You should also generate a random noise term, use this in the computation of your "response", but not include it as predictor in your model. That was just an aside, it doesn't explain nor change the problem.

First I thought what you demonstrated is an [omitted variable bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias), but it can't be, since your predictors are uncorrelated by construction. Thus, theoretically, your second regression should estimate a coefficient of 2. I reproduced your example in Stata, and the problem vanishes if you have enough observations; doing 1000 instead of 10 gives me a coefficient of $2.5$ instead of $-27$ on predictor 2 (I have a different seed though) - much closer. Thus, asymptotically, this should not be a problem.

Note that the effect of predictor2 need not be underestimated (negative). Run your regression a couple of times more (no seed) and you will see that it can also be overestimated.

Here is the new explanation: each observation of predictor2 $x_i$ is a realization of the random normal variable $N(3,1)$. $y$ (response) is a function of $x$ and $z$ (predictor1) and some noise. What OLS tries to do is attribute changes in $y$ to the predictors, in this case only $x$. This is what $$\hat{\beta}=\frac{Cov(x,y)}{Var(x)}$$ reflects. Now $Cov(y,x)=1/N\sum_i^N (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$, that is, it tells us how much $x$ and $y$ "co-move" (tend to go above their means $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ or below together). Since we omit predictor1 $z$, there can be 4 different cases for a given observation $i$. (1) $y_i$ is large (above mean) and $x_i$ is large or (2) both are small (below mean). Since both move in the same direction, this tends to make Cov positive. If $y_i$ is above the mean, then $z_i$ (realization of predictor1) was in most cases positive as well. But because the effect of $z$ is 25 times the effect of $x$, the coefficient of $x$ in these cases is overestimated.

Example: It's like having two employees in a firm producing crossword puzzles, but employee 1 is 25x as productive as employee 2. Now an accountant tries to estimate how much the employees contribute to the firms' crossword puzzle production, but he forgets employee 1 in the calculation. He does this by regressing firm production on employee time clocked. Suppose both employees always work together long or short hours (always begin and leave together). The accountant then overestimates the productivity of employee 2, because overall production and employee 2 working times co-move a lot. To the accountant, it looks as if employee 2 is responsible for all the output, consequently he must have been very productive in the time he worked. But in reality, this is all employee 1's work.

In remaining case (3) when $y_i$ is large and $x_i$ is small, it actually looks as if small values of $x$ lead to large values of $y$, so the effect of $x$ on $y$ is underestimated. The same holds for the remaining case (4) ($y_i$ is small and $x_i$ is large). Because we have only 10 observations, it is quite random whether cases (1) and (2), or cases (3) and (4) prevail. This is why it can go either way: the effect can be over- or underestimated. In very large samples, however, those over- and underestimations should cancel out, and we get the right coefficient for $x$.

OLS results for 10 observations (again demonstrating the problem):

```
      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      10
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,     8) =    1.53
       Model |   3575.0212     1   3575.0212           Prob > F      =  0.2516
    Residual |  18726.9444     8  2340.86805           R-squared     =  0.1603
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0553
       Total |  22301.9656     9  2477.99618           Root MSE      =  48.383

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    response |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  predictor2 |  -27.06526   21.90087    -1.24   0.252    -77.56875    23.43823
       _cons |   343.1629   138.8042     2.47   0.039      23.0798     663.246
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

OLS results for 1000 observations (solving the problem):

```
      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =    1000
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,   998) =    2.58
       Model |  6396.16144     1  6396.16144           Prob > F      =  0.1088
    Residual |  2477369.09   998  2482.33376           R-squared     =  0.0026
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.0016
       Total |  2483765.25   999   2486.2515           Root MSE      =  49.823

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    response |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  predictor2 |   2.509032   1.563063     1.61   0.109    -.5582357    5.576299
       _cons |   148.5405    9.53532    15.58   0.000     129.8289    167.2521
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Stata code:

```
clear
set obs 10 //10 observations
set seed 111
gen predictor1=rnormal(3,1) //generate variables
gen predictor2=rnormal(6,1)
gen noise=rnormal(0,3)
gen response=2+50*predictor1+2*predictor2+noise //include random error

reg response predictor1 predictor2 //ols
reg response predictor2

clear
set obs 1000
set seed 111
gen predictor1=rnormal(3,1)
gen predictor2=rnormal(6,1)
gen noise=rnormal(0,3)
gen response=2+50*predictor1+2*predictor2+noise //include random error

reg response predictor2
```

Comment: Although I know there's a logical explanation, I'm struggling to get an intuitive feel for why the beta for `predictor2` switches from 2 to -3.467 dependent on whether `predictor1` is in model and dependent on sample size of `predictor2`. Just to clarify: what exactly does 'realization' mean? When you say 'x 1 SD below the mean' what mean are you refering to?

Comment: Hi luciano; I think my first explanation wasn't right. Here is a new one, this time with an example that hopefully makes things more intuitive. Note also that the coefficient for predictor2 need not necessarily become negative. Try running the regression again without seed.